# How to display the attached view of a viewmodel as a dialog with MaterialDesignThemes?

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro, material-design-in-xaml

i am trying to get the View of a ViewModel by calling GetView() but it is returning null.

I also tried to activte the viewModel before calling GetView() same result.

```cs
var viewModel = IoC.Get<ProfilesManagementViewModel>();
var view = viewModel.GetView(); // returns null
```

right now i have to instantiate the view and viewmodel manually like this:

```cs
var profilesView = new ProfilesManagementView()
{
    DataContext = new ProfilesManagementViewModel()
};

// This method takes an object as the Content of the dialog.
await DialogHost.Show(profilesView, _dialogHostId);
```

All my Views are UserControl.

So how can i get the the View of a ViewModel ? What am i missing here ?

Comment: Why do you need to get hold of the view? Use the window manager to show the dialog and it does all of the plumbing for you.

Comment: @JackHughes the MaterialDesignThemes has its own dialogs system, which i want to use because it fits more with the styles and for consistency overall. I will be using that system for most of my dialogs. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/srsFVhT.png)

Comment: Create a IWindowMaterialManager which inherits IWindowManager... This has been done countless times with controls like Telerik and Syncfusion as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124065/issues-using-telerik-radwindow-and-custom-windowmanager-in-caliburn-micro